# Converting OVF to physical machine

Tags: vmware, virtualization, hyper-v, esxi

I'm looking to convert an OVF file to run on a physical machine on it's own. A company we own are slowly separating from our network to run on their own and their phone server doesn't require virtualization - a physical machine with 1GB of ram will easily suffice.

So I've exported to OVF locally, but I have no idea how I could run this on a physical machine. I've looked up as much as I can, but I can only find things relating to the opposite direction (physical to OVF).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ghost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_%28software%29) to create an image of the VM and then restore it on a physical machine, but it is possible you'll face driver conflicts.

Comment: Aren't all the drivers on ESXi generic? So we could just add the third party drivers on boot?